# Images in Symfony2

Tags: php, image, symfony, assets

I am new in Symfony 2 and i need your help. I want to output pictures uploaded by user to `web/uploads/photos`. But I dont know how I can access to that files, always get `404 error`. I read this pages:
[sf 1](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html),
[sf 2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/jpeg_optimize.html), and some articles on stackoverflow, but I realy havent answer. Please can somebody explain how I can do that?

Here is some code(maybe its be useful).

Get path in controller:

```
$pathToImages = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../web';
```

Try to get image in view:

```
<img src="{{ pathToImages }}/uploads/car_photos/{{ carPhotos.path }}">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use

```
<img src="{{ asset('uploads/car_photos/' ~ carPhotos.path) }}" />
```

if image folder is located under web folder

Comment: what mean  that symbol `~` ?

Comment: thats the twig string concatination like the "." in default php

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **asset** helper to generate the path.

The path helper goes directly to your web folder for example.

```
<img src="{{ asset('uploads/car_photos/' ~ carPhotos.path) }}" />
```